# In Mongoose (mongodb node.js), how to update existing values and insert missing, without removing unspecified values?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database

I'm trying to maintain an instantaneous statistics block, e.g.;

```
model = {
  id: 123,
  stats: {
    fooCount: 117,
    barCount: 175,
    bazCount: 654
  }
}
```

...and be able to update an existing record, but only specify the *new* values, like this:

```
model.update({
  '_id': 123,
    stats: {
      fooCount: 118 
    }
});
```

...without blowing away the old values in `stats`.  Is this possible without writing too much more code around my updates?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be using a [$set](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-$set) operator in your update like so:

```
var conditions = { _id: 123 };
var update = { $set: { fooCount: 118 }};
var options = { upsert: true };

model.update(conditions, update, options, callback);
```

There are many more operators that will be of interest on that MongoDB page as well.